# Disable VAT conditionally for specific product categories on Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, woocommerce, checkout

In woocommerce I am using [Timologia for WooCommerce](https://el.wordpress.org/plugins/timologia-for-woocommerce/) plugin, which checks if user wants invoice or plain receipt (this is required in Greece). So this plugin add a select field in checkout page with "No" *(default)* or "Yes" as options.

If customer select "Yes" then "zero vat" is applied for products in specific categories and everything works fine in the checkout page.

**But when customer place the order**, on the order received page and on backend (order edit page) the specific item prices are not anymore without VAT.

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'tfwc_taxexempt_checkout_based_invoice_choice' ); 

function tfwc_taxexempt_checkout_based_invoice_choice( $post_data ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt( false );
    parse_str($post_data);
    if ( $billing_timologio == 'Y' ) 

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_tax_class', 'wc_diff_rate_for_user', 1, 2 );

    function wc_diff_rate_for_user( $tax_class, $product ) {

    // let's get all the product category for this product...

    $terms = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) { // checking each category 

    // if it's one of the category we'er looking for
    if(in_array($term->term_id, array(228,231,222))) {
        $tax_class = 'Zero Rate';
        // found it... no need to check other $term
        break;
    }
}

    return $tax_class;
  }
}
```

This code was working fine on WC version 2.X, **and stopped working fine in version 3+**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 3**

The plugin and your code are outdated, with some mistakes and errors. In the code below I am using another way with ajax and `WC_Session`.

> #### The "Tax rate" behavior on products entered including taxes.
>
> To make any code that manipulate tax rates effective, **the products prices need to be entered excluding taxes.** If not, additional code is required to grab the product price excluding taxes as custom cart item data, to make the "Zero rate" tax effective.

I have added a custom function partially copied from the plugin code, that adds a checkout select field `billing_timologio`, to make the code testable.

Also the add to cart ajax button is replaced by a button linked to single product pages for the defined product categories, as we add the product price excluding taxes as custom cart item data.

The code (only for Woocommerce version 3.3+):

```
// Your product categories settings
function get_my_terms(){
    return array( 'clothing' );
    return array( 222, 228, 231 );
}

// Change add to cart ajax button to a button linked to single product pages for specific product categories
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'conditionally_replace_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );
function conditionally_replace_add_to_cart( $html, $product ) {
    if ( has_term( get_my_terms(), 'product_cat', $product_id )  && $product->is_type('simple') ) {
        // Set HERE your button link
        $link = get_permalink($product_id);
        $text = __("Read More", "woocommerce");
        $html = '<a href="' . $link . '" class="button alt add_to_cart_button">' . $text . '</a>';
    }
    return $html;
}

// Adding a custom checkout select field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_billing_fields', 20, 1 );
function custom_billing_fields($billing_fields) {

    $billing_fields['billing_timologio'] = array(
        'type'        => 'select',
        'label'       => __('INVOICE'),
        'placeholder' => _x('INVOICE', 'placeholder'),
        'required'    => false,
        'class'       => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'       => true,
        'options'     => array(
            'N' => __('No'),
            'Y' => __('Yes'),
        ),
        'value' => '',
    );
    return $billing_fields;
}

// The jQuery Ajax script
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_script' );
function custom_checkout_script() {
    // Only checkout page
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ):

    // Removing WC_Session "
    if( WC()->session->__isset('billing_timologio') ){
        WC()->session->__unset('billing_timologio');
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        if (typeof wc_checkout_params === 'undefined')
            return false;

        // On load reset value to 'N'
        $('#billing_timologio_field select').val('N');

        // On change (Ajax)
        $('#billing_timologio_field select').change( function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'get_ajax_billing_timologio',
                    'b_timologio': $(this).val() == 'Y' ? 1 : 0,
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

// The Wordpress Ajax receiver
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_ajax_billing_timologio', 'get_ajax_billing_timologio' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ajax_billing_timologio', 'get_ajax_billing_timologio' );
function get_ajax_billing_timologio() {
    if ( $_POST['b_timologio'] == '1' ){
        WC()->session->set('billing_timologio', '1');
    } else {
        WC()->session->set('billing_timologio', '0');
    }
    die();
}

// Save the product price excluding tax as custom cart item data
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_price_excl_vat_as_custom_cart_item_data', 20, 3);
function add_price_excl_vat_as_custom_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    if ( ! wc_prices_include_tax() )
        return $cart_item_data;

    $_product_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id;
    $product = wc_get_product($_product_id); // The WC_Product Object

    // Save the price excluding tax as custom cart item data
    if( has_term( get_my_terms(), 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
        $cart_item_data['price_excl_tax'] = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_price() ) );
    }

    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Changing conditionally specific items tax rate
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'zero_tax_items_based_on_invoice_choice', 30, 1 );
function zero_tax_items_based_on_invoice_choice( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Check for product categories and enabled "billing_timologio" field
        if( has_term( get_my_terms(), 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) && WC()->session->get('billing_timologio') ){
            // Set the item tax rate to "Zero rate"
            $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class('Zero Rate');

            // Set price excluding taxes
            if( isset($cart_item['price_excl_tax']) ){
                $cart_item['data']->set_price($cart_item['price_excl_tax']);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> On order received, order view and (admin) order edit pages, **the tax will be set to "Zero Rate"** for the specific items when customer has selected "Yes" for "BILLING INVOICE" (ΤΙΜΟΛΟΓΙΟ).
>
> The related product price remaining to the defined product categories **will have this time the correct price excluding taxes**…

---

**Original answer.**

I seems that there is 2 errors:

- The first is `$product->id` to be replaced by `$product->get_id()`
- The second, you need to put the internal function outside

Also the code can be simplified.

Without any guaranty as your code can't be tested for real, try this instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'tfwc_taxexempt_checkout_based_invoice_choice' ); 
function tfwc_taxexempt_checkout_based_invoice_choice( $post_data ) {
    WC()->customer->set_is_vat_exempt( false );
    
    parse_str($post_data);
    
    if ( $billing_timologio == 'Y' ) 
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_tax_class', 'wc_diff_rate_for_user', 1, 2 );
    }
}

function wc_diff_rate_for_user( $tax_class, $product ) {
    // Checking for specific product categories
    if( has_term( array(228,231,222), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        return 'Zero Rate';
    }
    return $tax_class;
}
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, if any one can help then it is you (your like my Yoda of woocommerce), it still works on checkout page, but order-received still shows the price with tax, I also tried with slug 'zero-rate' but i dont think that is the problem because if it was then the price wouldnt change on the checkout, can i send you the url of the site here ? or its not allowed. Also above you mention $order->get_id(), where should I put that?

Comment: the only time i can know if the certain products are tax exempt are in the checkout page where the customer selects 'yes' in a dropdown, i just dont understand why since update_checkout function shows everything ok at checkout, why by placing the order it over writes the price, is there an update_cart function that i could trigger at the same time?

Comment: so gratefull that you are trying to help me, I used my own plugin [link](https://el.wordpress.org/plugins/timologia-for-woocommerce/) , which checks if user wants invoice or plain receipt (this is required in greece), in this plugin I am now implementing the above code to zero rate products that  are in certain categories if customer selects he wants invoice

Comment: @JohnAthanasiou Could you please retry the code and give some feed back on it.  It should works on any case now (also with product prices set excluding taxes). Thank you

Comment: can not get it to work , even if the checkout page works, the price in the order received page and the backend orders will always show the price with VAT, instead of using a custom cart item data, can we not just get the cart item at checkout and deduct e.g. 24% ?